# What happens when baker's, butcher's, etc. are in the plural?

Tags: grammatical-number, british-english, orthography, possessives, apostrophe

If the singular it is:

> The baker's and the butcher's are closed on Sundays.

Which one is the plural?

> - Bakers and butchers are closed on Sundays.
> - Bakers' and butchers' are closed on Sundays.

Answer (score 3):

Bakers and butchers, in the plural, do not require an apostrophe unless it is referring to something belonging to the bakers and butchers - such as: **"All butchers' *shops* are closed on Sundays."**

Your first example is actually an abbreviated way of saying, ***"The baker's shop is closed on Sundays."*** Otherwise, it would be ***"The baker does not do business on Sundays."***

Comment: So if I mean "butcher's shops", can I say "all butchers' are closed on Sundays"?