# Meat is sold at the butchers' or meat is sold at butchers?

Tags: grammar

I'm not an English speaker. Could you tell me what is wrong with the sentence below?

Meat is sold at butchers.

The correction says meat is sold at the butchers'. I have no idea why need to have the before butcher'.

Comment: The first one is plural. Meat is sold at all the butchers. The second one refers to one butcher. Meat is sold at the butcher's place.

Comment: @Sprottenwels It is more complicated than that. Suppose I say "I bumped into Mr Jones at the butcher's". That means a specific "butcher's (shop)". - see my answer.

Comment: Answered at [What happens when baker's, butcher's, etc. are in the plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/119779/what-happens-when-bakers-butchers-etc-are-in-the-plural/119786#119786) (Kristina Lopez's answer), but I seem to remember other similar threads.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming for this purpose that the apostrophe in your title is incorrectly placed - and should be before the s. Otherwise it would be *Meat is sold at (all) butchers' (shops)*.

***Meat is sold at the butcher's*** is an idiomatic expression. It can be referring to a specific butcher's shop. Or it can refer to any and all butchers, in the same way people say *I love swimming in the sea*. The latter doesn't refer to any particular sea, even though the definite article is used. Similarly: *I love the fresh air*, *I enjoy the sense of achievement*. These uses permit the definite article to describe something in general.

***Meat is sold at butchers*** This is equally idiomatic and could mean *Meat is sold in butchers' (shops)*, with the word *shops* elided. If you intended *butchers* to refer to individuals rather than shops it would be idiomatic to say *meat is sold **by** butchers*.

Answer (score 0):

Oftentimes, in standard English (in the US), we would include the definite article ("the"), and we would say:

> You can buy meat at the butcher's.

(which is a shorter way of saying, "You can buy meat at the butcher's shop")

-or-

> You can buy meat at the butchers'.

(which is just a shorter way of saying, "You can buy meat at the butchers' shop" or "You can buy meat at the butchers' shops").

For most purposes, the meaning of both of these is the same.
However, there could be a slight difference in nuance between the two.

"The butcher's," with the apostrophe *before* the s, could be used to imply that there is one particular shop being discussed, especially if there is one main butcher at that shop or if there is a single owner of the shop.

"The butchers'," with the apostrophe *after* the s, could be used to imply that there are several butchers working at a single shop, or that there is a group of owners of the shop. Or it could be used if the speaker/writer is making a general statement about many different butcher shops (for example: "Fresh sausage is available at the butchers' throughout Vienna").

[Oxford's Learner's Dictionary says](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/butcher_1) that the singular for a shop that sells meat has an apostrophe -s while the plural does not:

> <sup>2</sup> **butcher’s** (pl. **butchers**) a shop/store that sells meat

Following that rule, a very general statement could be made by leaving out the definite article and the apostrophe:

> Meat is sold at butchers.

Some examples:

> Variations on cured pork ... are signature flavorings for Roman dishes, found **at butchers** like Viola....

^ *Fodor's Rome, with The Best City-Walks and City Day Trips*, 2013

> Instead, you want to purchase lard that is refrigerated, which you can find **at butchers**, Mexican markets, or at a farmers' market.

^ *The Homsesick Texan Cookbook*, by Lisa Fain, 2011

> Hog casings seem to be pretty available at butchers shops if you just ask, or you can find them easily online.

^ [Serious Eats](http://www.seriouseats.com/2013/08/homemade-merguez-sausage-recipe.html), 2013

> In supermarkets and specialty food shops, endless varieties of cheese and sausage can now be found much more readily: mascarpone and goat cheeses from Italy; cow's milk cheeses from France and Spain; chorizo, andouille and boudin sausages **at butchers** with customers attuned to Latin American and European cuisines.

^ [an article](http://www.nytimes.com/1997/10/05/nyregion/how-roast-beef-gave-way-to-lemongrass-and-focaccia.html) in *New York Times*, 1997

Note that dry-cleaners' shops are treated a little differently. (Dry-cleaners clean clothes. "Cleaners" is the shortened form, and it is used much more often nowadays than the more formal "dry-cleaners.")

> I will stop by the cleaners to pick up my suits.

or

> Don't forget to take your claim ticket whenever you leave your clothes at the cleaners.

The definite article is almost always used for "cleaners" (in other words, it's almost always "**the** cleaners"), and usually no apostrophe is used.

Comment: Interesting, but you don't add any substantiating references. I'd certainly like to see one for << Ordinarily, in standard English (in the US), we would include the definite article ("the"), and we would say:

...

or _You can buy meat at the butchers'._ >>.

Comment: In your "Fresh meat is available at the butchers' throughout Vienna", I don't think I would include a definite article. It is not quite the same thing as the very general statement "Meat is bought at the butcher's". In your example you are talking about some specific butchers and they are plural. Hence the definite article doesn't fit. I also do not see a need for the apostrophe, unless you say "butchers' shops".

Comment: @WS2 I don't see a _need_ for one then either.

Comment: @WS2, I updated my answer to include examples of "at butchers."

Comment: @Shosht What I was getting at was the most general of all statement - where I would perhaps include an apostrophe. Consider this: three-year-old child says "Where does meat come from daddy?" As it's just before bedtime and not a moment to go into the gory detail -  you say "Oh, meat comes from the butcher's" - but not meaning any specific butcher. The Vienna example differed from that.